# How can I keep trailing zeros in a Kendo UI numericTextBox?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to build a numeric input widget using Kendo UI. I am able to set the format so that trailing zeros are not truncated when the field does not have focus, but when the field does have focus, the trailing zeros disappear.

I have an example at http://dojo.telerik.com/eBevU and the relevant bits are listed below:

```
<div id="add-product" class="demo-section k-content">
  <ul id="fieldlist">
    <li>
      <label for="numeric">Input</label>
      <input id="numeric" type="number" value="17" min="0" max="100" step="1" style="width: 100%;" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // create NumericTextBox from input HTML element
    $("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
      format: "n5",
      decimals: 5
    });
  });
</script>
```

This example shows "17.00000" in the input box before it has focus, and "17" after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found is to basically reconstruct the value using the format specified in the widget configuration i.e. adding the decimal separator (if needed) and the missing trailing zeros. Bind the function below to the focus event of the input.

```
function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var widget = input.data("kendoNumericTextBox");

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (widget !== undefined && input.val() !== "") {
          var format = widget._format(widget.options.format);
          var decimals = widget.options.decimals;

          if (decimals > 0) {
              var inputValue = input.val();
              var digits = inputValue.split(format["."]);

              if (digits.length == 1)
                  inputValue = inputValue + format["."];

              var l = digits[0].length + 1 + decimals;
              while (inputValue.length < l)
                  inputValue = inputValue + "0";

              input.val(inputValue);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

You can find [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/eBevU/9) your example modified.

Answer (score 0):

The only way (that I have experienced) kendo will retain the decimal places when focused is if the number already has a value with the specified precision, otherwise it removes them. You could try and modify the step so that the user can increase the value by smaller amounts.

```
$("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
     format: "n5",
     decimals: 5,
     step: 0.00001
});
```

Good luck.